# Как программно запретить "Overlay scrollbar" в Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, eclipse, любой-язык, swt

Я пытаюсь портировать на `Ubuntu` свое приложение, построенное на `SWT`, и столкнулся с проблемой с т. наз. **"overlay scrollbars"**. Когда программа работает из-под `Eclipse`, всё нормально, но когда она запускается из `JAR`, скроллбары становятся **"overlay scrollbars"** - превращаются в тонкие оранжевые полоски. При этом события от скроллбаров тоже меняются (видимо, какие-то другие значения в `stateMask` или в `detail`), и программа перестает их обрабатывать (игнорирует). Для моей программы такие скроллбары категорически не подходят (даже если бы я разобрался с событиями), мне нужны традиционные скроллбары и нужно самому особым образом обрабатывать их события.

Исправить это поведение легко - достаточно добавить `export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0` в `~/.profile`, но это негодный вариант - мне нужно, чтобы любой пользователь мог запустить программу, просто ткнув мышкой по JAR-файлу, без необходимости делать какие-то специальные настройки в системе,
поэтому я ищу способ сделать то же самое из своего программного кода. Я новичок в программировании для `Linux`, и, видимо, плохо понимаю, как можно решать подобные задачи программно. Пробовал в своем коде перед загрузкой SWT выполнить

```
 System.setProperty("LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR", "0");
```

и

```
 new ProcessBuilder("export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0").start();
```

но ни то, ни другое эффекта не дает. При этом установка переменной `SWT_GTK3=0` таким вот образом

```
 System.setProperty("SWT_GTK3","0");
```

очевидно, срабатывает, т. е. дает ожидаемый эффект. Возможно, дело в том, что `LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR` срабатывает только при входе пользователя, а `SWT_GTK3` - в любой момент, лишь бы была уже установлена к моменту загрузки SWT.

Как можно побороть эти **"overlay scrollbars"** из программного кода? 
P.S. Работающие решения для других языков, возможно, помогут найти решение и для JAVA - пробема не JAVA-специфическая.

Comment: На английском SO предлагают запускать из скрипта, в котором предварительно устанавливать переменную окружения, но это и без SO понятно, я более элегантное решение ищу.

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42048599/how-to-disable-overlay-scrollbars-programmatically-ubuntu-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существуют способы устанавливать переменные окружения для работающего экземпляра JVM (под которым выполняется наша программа), например вот так:

```
    private static void setEnv(Map<String, String> newEnv) throws Exception {
      Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
      Class<?> cl = env.getClass();
      Field field = cl.getDeclaredField("m");
      field.setAccessible(true);
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      Map<String, String> envMap = (Map<String, String>) field.get(env);
      envMap.putAll(newEnv);
    }
```

(идея взята из ответов на https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java)

Однако в моем случае мне нужно устанавливать переменные для библиотек, чей код работает не под JVM (а именно, для GTK), так что этот метод не решает моей проблемы.

По некотором размышлении я понял, что я хочу устанавливать переменные окружения для родительского по отношению к JVM процесса, так что мне нужно сначала установить переменные окружения, а затем запустить JVM, которая будет выполнять мою программу -- тогда эти переменные будут влиять на библиотеки даже тогда, когда их код выполняется не из-под JVM.

Так что логика должна быть какой-то такой:

```
 if (нужных переменных нет) {
   запустить процесс, который {
     установит нужные переменные;
     запустит второй экземпляр JVM с моей программой;  
   }
   выйти; 
 }
 // здесь переменные будут уже установлены 
 делаем всё то, что хотели
```

На Java код может выглядеть таким образом:

```
public class SecondVM {
  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    if (    System.getenv("SWT_GTK3") == null
         || System.getenv("LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR") == null )  
    { 
      URL classResource = SecondVM.class.getResource("SecondVM.class");
      boolean fromJar = classResource.getProtocol().equals("rsrc");

      String exePath = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath();
      exePath =  new File(exePath).getAbsolutePath().replaceFirst("\\.$", "").replaceFirst("bin$", "");
      if (!exePath.endsWith(System.getProperty("file.separator")))
        exePath += System.getProperty("file.separator");

      String[] script = {
          "/bin/bash", "-c",
          "export SWT_GTK3=0; "
           + "export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0; "
           + (fromJar? // TODO: Put the proper paths, packages and class names here
              "java -jar " + exePath + "SecondVM.jar" :         // if runs from jar
              "java -cp ./bin/:../ExtLibs/swt_linux64/swt.jar " // if runs from under Eclipse or somewhat alike 
              + "com.m_v.test.SecondVM")
      };

      try {
        Process p = new ProcessBuilder(script).start();

        // When jar is run from a bash script, it kills the second VM when exits.
        // Let it has some time to take a breath
        p.waitFor(12, TimeUnit.HOURS);
      } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
      System.exit(0);
    }

    // Now the env vars are OK. We can use SWT with normal scrollbars    
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    // .... do watever we need 
  }
}
```

В случае запуска JAR-файла из shell-скрипта, приходится дожидаться окончания вложенного процесса, прежде чем выходить из первого, так что такое решение ведет к накладным расходам в виде двух одновременно работающих экземпляров JVM. Если нет необходимости обеспечивать возможность запуска из скрипта, можно заменить `p.waitFor(12, TimeUnit.HOURS);` на `p.waitFor(12, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` или, возможно, вовсе его убрать (я не пробовал), так что у нас будет работать единственный экземпляр JVM, как при запуске обычной программы на Java.

Рабочий пример кода с текстовым полем (`text` widget - как по-русски?) и скроллбаром лежит на http://ideone.com/eRjePQ