# Как сделать чтобы программа перезагружалась по нажатию кнопки [Java]

Tags: java

Как сделать чтобы программа перезагружалась когда нажимаешь JButton программа закрывается и автоматически открывается?

Comment: Написать другую программу, которая будет запускать и останавливать нужную программу по нажатию кнопки

Comment: зачем вам требуется перезагрузка программы?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Использовать такое можно только в крайнем случае. В моем кейсе это была невозможность убить статику, внутри зависимости.

Есть один способ, он не стабилен по ряду причин, имеет недостатки, однако я им пользовался и в предсказуемом окружении он работал и работает по сей день.

Суть в запуске нового экземпляра `jvm` с теми же аргументами, с которыми запущен текущий экземпляр, который Вы хотите перезапустить, и немедленном завершении работы текущего экземпляра.

1. Создайте для запуска приложения bat или sh файл.
2. Привяжите на кнопку запуск этого файла через Runtime.exec() и потом завершайте работу Вашей программы.

Конечно можно довести до ума метод и находить и запускать нужную jvm из кода, но мне это не было надо и я этого не делал.

Большой недостаток этого способа - это не сработает в ide или надо еще придумывать как сделать так, чтобы это заработало в ide, если Вам это вдруг необходимо.

Я остановился на рантайме.

P.S. собрал пример, который работает из ide (у меня idea), допилить до ума предлагаю уже по месту =) тут можно дорабатывать его еще долго, прокинуть аргументы `jvm` например, учесть запуск из `jar` и тому подобные кейсы, общий принцип остается тот же.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Restart {

    public static final String Q = "\"";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JButton button = new JButton("close");
        button.addActionListener(evt -> {
            try {
                Class<?> clazz = Restart.class;
                String classPath = clazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
                        .getLocation().toString().split("file:/")[1];
                String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
                String cmd = Q + javaHome  + "/bin/java" + Q
                        + " -cp " + Q + classPath + Q
                        + " " + clazz.getSimpleName();
                System.out.println("cmd = " + cmd);
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                System.exit(0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("cannot restart");
            }
        });
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("restart jvm");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(300,100));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Насколько я помню, у меня под линуксом из-под эклипса вполне нормально запускался и работал второй экземпляр JVM, только отлаживаться во втором экземпляре было нельзя, но меня это не сильно заботило -- код в общем уже был отлажен, а на крайний случай вывод на консоль использовал.

Comment: @m.vokhm я раньше для продакшена не включал такую возможность, т.е перезапуск работал только в собранном приложении, теперь решил обратное для примера сделать

Answer (score 3):

В соседнем ответе `@dreamsicle` верно отметил, что в общем случае намного проще и "честнее" очистить состояние приложения, чем перезапускать его, так что я советую сильно подумать, *действительно ли необходимо* вам его перезапускать. Если действительно необходимо, то можно сделать так, как советует `@Stranger in the Q`.

У меня в свое время была необходимость перезапускать `JVM` и под ним новый экземпляр приложения, чтобы приложение работало в среде с определенными значениями переменных окружения, и при этом по ТЗ нельзя было пользоваться дополнительными shell-скриптами, я сделал перезапуск по такому же принципу, как описал `@Stranger in the Q`, но непосредственно из кода программы. Работает, кажется, достаточно надёжно -- ни я сам, ни пользователи с проблемами не сталкивались. Подробнее см. [мой вопрос и мой же ответ на него](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623548/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-overlay-scrollbar-%D0%B2-ubuntu)